# Is "very" an adjective?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

We all know that there is a sentence "He is a very man". In this sentence I suppose that
"very" refers to "man":noun. So in this case, very should be treated as an adjective, isn't it?

Comment: "He is a very man" doesn't make sense: normally one would say "a very [something] man", e.g., "a very tall man" or "a very strange man".

Comment: The problem is that we **do not**  "all know that there is a sentence *He is **a** very man*. === In fact,  *"He is **a** very man".* is meaningless and wrong. Do you mean "He is **the** very man"?

Comment: @Greybeard: It is indeed rare, but it does crop up [from time to time](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+very+man&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20very%20man%3B%2Cc0). For instance, it occurs in Shakespeare's [Troilus and Cressida](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/troilus_cressida/full.html): "They say he is a very man per se". And googling "a very man" throws up various religious references to Jesus Christ, Job etc.

Comment: If people wouldn't try to cram 18 different things into 8 odd-shaped categories, it would be a better world. Once more, questions like "Is `Word` a `Partofspeech`?" are hopeless to answer, useless even when answered correctly, and totally confusing. It doesn't matter what you call them; they're gonna behave whatever way they behave, and the devil with the textbook definitions and grammar.

Comment: I see, so it is not a common use and it mostly does not make sense for people, right?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, it seems to answer my question partly.

Comment: @Greybeard, it might be "He is the very man", because I saw it in a movie. If it is so, what does it mean?

Comment: @Ranger - Thanks - I'm sure it will be "He is **the** very man" - "***a*** very man/[noun]" is now obsolete and sounds weird. As an adjective, "very" used to mean *"real; genuine; authentic; complete in all attributes* But very(adj.) is now mainly emphatic and means "exact/actual/most appropriate]." It is found in such constructions as "Those were your very [=exact/precise/actual] words." and "This is the very  [=exactly right/precise/actual] thing I need!" and, of course, "Ah! Look! Here is John, the very man I was talking about" = *precisely the man* I was talking about.

Comment: @John Lawler At last a part-answer to my first question here! 18.

Answer (score 0):

“Very” is sometimes (infrequently) used as an adjective. A dictionary should cover this. But “He is a very man” is not a common or normal-sounding sentence. Are you sure you’re not misremembering “He’s the very man (for __)”?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure, because I saw the sentence in  a movie.

Comment: If you **saw** it in a movie, it must have been in the subtitles, and subtitles are not a place where one should look for examples of English.